# Install root CA Certificates in a client, C++ with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have to implement a system to install root certificates, the client will receive a json message from the server with the certificate inside.
I have a doubt, how to implement this, because I don´t know if I have to use a store(X509_store from OpenSSL, programmatically) for this or just write the string to a pem file in the assigned directory.
Later, I should be able to delete this certificates or replace for new ones, installing the certificate with recently notBefore date.
In a nutshell, I´d like to know if I have to use store or not for this.
This is for Debian system.

Thanks.

Comment: You should specify for what system. For Debian based copy cert to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/` then `update-ca-certificates`

Comment: Is it just your application that needs the root certificate(s) or other 3rd party applications (or even system) ?

Comment: It is for my application that needs install the new root certificates sent by other app through a message that I parser. Do I need update the store as mention in the comment before? Any instruction from api OpenSSL, to emulate update-ca-certificates?